# Show and hide categories

Tags: html

I like many things when you click on Vehicules, to show or hide sub catégories.I tried but it does not work

```
<ul class="ul_categories">
    <li class="li_title_categories">Vehicules</li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-2-Voitures.htm">Voitures</a></li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-3-Motos-scooters.htm">Motos/scooters</a></li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-4-Caravanes-Camping-cars.htm">Caravanes/Camping-cars</a></li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-5-Utilitaires.htm">Utilitaires</a></li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-6-Accessoires-pieces.htm">Accessoires/pièces</a></li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-7-Pieces-detachees.htm">Pièces détachées</a></li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-8-Nautisme.htm">Nautisme</a></li>
    <li class="li_categories"><a href="Categorie-9-Velos.htm">Vélos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/QS4E6/
But I don't get your question. What are you trying to archieve? Do you want to hide li's with JavaScript or CSS? What are the conditions? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I'll try to explain better.Sorry for my english, I'll try better expliquer.Je would defauft by the categories or hide and when they click on Vehicles appear. A bit like a hide / show

Comment: When a user clicks a link in your list, a new page will be opened. If this is not what you expect, you should either prevent it's default behavior, or choose another DOM structure.

Comment: look at the bottom of the page. Here are the sub-categories that I would like to display and hide http://www.script-pag.com/demo/fr/

Comment: You do not understand my request?

Comment: I think nobody can understand. How and why would you like to do that? PHP? CSS? Javascript? We can guess but don't know!

Comment: I managed : http://jsfiddle.net/tatane/LEL5q/

Comment: OK, now I understand what your question was. :)

Comment: Now I must arrive at my code to run several categories at the same time

Comment: How to make when you click on the cat1 cat2 column does not open? http://jsfiddle.net/tatane/LEL5q/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/LEL5q/4/

First, I simplified you HTML like this:

```
<ul class="ul_categories">
    <li class="li_title">cat</li>
    <li class="li_categories hidden">Button1</li>
    <li class="li_categories hidden">Button2</li>
    <li class="li_categories hidden">Button3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul_categories">
    <li class="li_title">cat</li>
    <li class="li_categories hidden">Button1</li>
    <li class="li_categories hidden">Button2</li>
    <li class="li_categories hidden">Button3</li>
</ul>
```

And then I simplified your JQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.li_title').on('click',function(){
        $(this).siblings('.li_categories').toggle();
    });

});
```

I also added one CSS Class called 'hidden' with the following Attributes:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And that's all!

Comment: Nice by cons how to hide the content of cat 2 if you click on cat 1 http://jsfiddle.net/tatane/LEL5q/33/